# Facebook comments on site post to Facebook profile, but unable to like the published post or comment (on the comment)

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments, facebook-comments

I have tried using all different plugins (facebook, facebook comments, seo facebook comments, and more), I have even added the application manualy (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ using html5 plugin code). All options do the same thing.

Comments show up that is all fine. Readers are able to comment on the website through the box, thats fine too. But then when I want to publish to facebook, all seems good too, it will publish it. But when I go to facebook and click on the published comment, it is not possible to like or comment (on the publish comment). Facebook shows the comment on the timeline, but clicking on it gives this message:

"Object cannot be liked
Unable to like this object because it is not accessible (it may have been removed or you may no longer have permission to see it)."

I can click the link in "John Doe has commented on a link" and it will take me to the page however.

Some other strange things that happen are (on the actual wp post) when you comment and have the "post to facebook" box checked, it won't publish straight away, but give the message "This comment has not yet been published to Facebook. Publish Comment". Only after clicking publish comment will it ask permission to publish on my profile.

And then when you want to delete the message, it will say "Oops Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can." Click delete again and it deletes. No fail every time on the second time after that message.

Please help me out, before I go crazy :P Website is tryajuice.com

I am also using Yoast WordPress SEO: Social, OneAll social login, which might influence it, but deactivating them all doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: no one with any answers, or the same issue?